# Eclipse ADB error [Ubuntu 13.04]

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, adb

So I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 and for the past many hours I've been trying to get eclipse (Eclipse Juno 4.2.2) to launch anything on my phone, or even just in the emulator, but to no success. Whenever I try to launch the app, I'm greeted with an adb not found error (/home/kiyoshi/Desktop/Development/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb not found), even though I have checked multiple times to make sure a file named adb is there.

I have also installed adb via command line so using commands such as 'adb devices' works fine, and I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong, even after looking through pages of other questions with similar problems.

[This screenshot shows the error when I try to launch anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ5gc.png)

Any help is appreciated,
thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message clearly states something different: "libncurses.so not found". So you probably missed to install the needed 32-bit stuff:

`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah, I guess I didn't properly read the error it was throwing, so thanks for correcting me! Works great now! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your device is in USB debugging mode. Then, restart the adb server by the console, going through is path and typing:

adb kill-server

then

adb start-server

Restart Eclipse and usb connection (unplug, plug)

hope it helps, it Always helps me