# Adb not responding with android studio on Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, android-studio

well it might not the best combo. Using first time Ubuntu (13.04) and the new Android Studio. ;)
However, if I try to start my app a error occurs with the message: "ADB not responding. You can wait more, or kill "adb" process manually and click 'Restart'". Of course tried the help from the message and restartet everything. Nothing help.

And yes I can start ADB directly and start a emu. Even the emu is started the error appear.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427197/eclipse-adb-error-ubuntu-13-04/16428211#16428211?

Answer (score 12):

You may require additional libraries:

```
# sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

From the page on [Troubleshooting Ubuntu](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html)

Comment: That package is obsolete :( and the help link is missing.

Comment: Try instead of ia32-libs: `sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0`

Answer (score 11):

On my machine I had to install lib32ncurses5 in order to have adb shipped with android studio to work

sudo apt-get install  lib32ncurses5

Comment: I'm running 64-bit Ubuntu, this solution should not apply to me, correct? When I run the command the terminal says, already at the newest version and problem still persists.

Answer (score 3):

go to `/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools` directory and change `adb` file permission.( Allow executing file as program )