# Can't get started with Android Studio for Ubuntu ADB error

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

I keep getting this error when I start Android Studio (AS) (I am not running Eclipse). I am running Ubuntu; I did a fresh install of Ubuntu and AS and this happened upon start up:

> ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill
>   "adb" and click 'Restart'

I have tried this solution: [ADB Not Responding - Wait More or Kill adb or Restart (Ubuntu 13) 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381790/adb-not-responding-wait-more-or-kill-adb-or-restart-ubuntu-13-64-bit)

and this: [Adb not responding with android studio on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701113/adb-not-responding-with-android-studio-on-ubuntu) as well as the duplicate link that follows.

I tried making an AVD and it doesn't want to run on there. I double checked that ADB is added to my PATH.

Is there more information I can provide? Any response with information or questions is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal, type `ps -u (your username)`, find the pid, and type `kill -9 (pid)`. If that doesn't work, use a higher number, such as `kill -15 (pid)`.

Answer (score -1):

When this happens to me I usually do `ps -ef` to find out `adb` pid, and then `kill -s 15 <adb_pid>`. After that everything works fine.

Comment: I searched the output of the command "ps -ef," and "adb" does not appear anywhere in the document. Am I looking for the wrong thing?